# Logging in before items are set in localStorage - JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an app with firebase but when I click log in, it does everything except setting the localStorage items. Tried awaiting and everything else I could think of

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(async (userCredential) => {
                const user = userCredential.user;
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", user.stsTokenManager.accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem("uid", user.uid);

                const devices = collection(db, "users", user.uid, "devices");
                const devicesSnap = await getDocs(devices);
                if(devicesSnap.docs.length >= 1) {
                    localStorage.setItem("first_charger", devicesSnap.docs[0].id);
                    localStorage.setItem("first_charger_name", devicesSnap.docs[0].data().deviceName + "/" + devicesSnap.docs[0].id);
                    const formattedChargers = formatChargers(devicesSnap.docs);
                    setChargers(formattedChargers);
                } else {
                    setChargers([]);
                }

                const cars = collection(db, "users", localStorage.getItem("uid"), "vehicles");
                const carsSnap = await getDocs(cars);
                if(carsSnap.docs.length >= 1) {
                    const formattedCars = formatCars(carsSnap.docs);
                    setCars(formattedCars);
                } else {
                    setCars([]);
                }

                setLoading(false);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: for debugging, does it work with a simple dummy value? `localStorage.setItem('dummy', 'value')`

Comment: @gru - Yes it works.

Comment: How and when do you verify the content of localStorage?

Comment: @gru - I print them on the screen and check the application tab and I there is nothing.

Comment: And your `user` object is available as well? `const user = userCredential.user; console.log('user', user)`

Comment: @gru - Yes it is. I have the data and the uid saves successfully in the localStorage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241893/discussion-between-imdarkk-and-gru).

Comment: @gru - Thank you. I put what you said in mind as to where I am verifying them and I put an if statement to check and if it's not already in localStorage I re-add it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an if statement that checks if it exists and if it doesn't it tries re-adding it

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("first_charger_name")) {
    localStorage.setItem("first_charger_name", devicesSnap.docs[0].data().deviceName + "/" + devicesSnap.docs[0].id);
}
```